# HTTP PUT request not updating field in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to make an API that can retrieve and update information inside of a database (MongoDB)
Retrieving information from said database is successful, my issue is updating the field.

Sending the PUT request returns 'Field replaced successfully', however whenever I make a GET request to verify that the information has been updated, it is unchanged.

I haven't tried many things due to a lack of understanding when it comes to Node.js
The expected result was for the field to be replaced, but after attempting to verify that the information was successfully replaced by the request's body, it was never changed. The API is made for the purpose of speeding up a task, and the code is my attempt at recreating a different API created by one of my old friends. His was near-instant.

The queries are as follows:

- key, which is required to send requests in the first place
- id, which is the requested field to be retrieved / update

```
var Express = require("express");
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var cors = require("cors")

const multer = require("multer")

var app = Express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(Express.json());

var connection_string = "connection-string"
var validKey = "60YGrhgU6MEz9E1UZmaMLFlAvKTbYGLGof3PRTmvAmxYWXQeeXIbjPiFhUUVaWqBc"

var databaseName = "data"
var database;

app.listen(5038, () => {
    MongoClient.connect(connection_string, (error, client) => {
        database = client.db(databaseName);
        console.log("Connected to MongoDB")
    });
})

app.get('/api/lsbg', (request, response) => {
    const key = request.query.key;
    const id = request.query.id;

    if (key !== validKey) {
        response.status(401).send({ "code": 401, "error": "Invalid key" })
    } else {
        if (!id) {
            database.collection("giver").find({}).forEach(doc => {
                response.send(doc)
            })
        } else if (id === 0) {
            database.collection("giver").find({}).forEach(doc => {
                response.send(doc)
            })
        } else {
            database.collection('giver').findOne({}, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    response.status(404).json({ "code": 500, error: 'Internal server error' });
                } else if (result && result.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                    response.json(result[id]);
                } else {
                    response.status(404).json({ "code": 404, error: `Could not find data of id ${id}` });
                }
            });
        }
    }
})

app.put('/api/lsbg', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const updatedValue = req.body; 

    const updateQuery = { [id]: updatedValue };

    database.collection('giver').updateOne(
        {},
        { $set: updateQuery },
        (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
            } else {
                res.json({ message: 'Field replaced successfully' });
            }
        }
    )
});
```

EDIT: The database structure looks like this.

```json
{
    "userId": {
        "customs": [
            "Sword",
            "Spear"
        ],
        "morphs": [
            "Knight",
            "Jester"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your front-end `put` request code to the question.

Comment: Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this code :

and your end-point request with a valid ID like this: http://localhost/3000/api/lsbg/{your id}

```js
app.put('/api/lsbg/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const updatedValue = req.body; 

    const updateQuery = { [id]: updatedValue };

    database.collection('giver').updateOne(
        {},
        { $set: updateQuery },
        (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
            } else {
                res.json({ message: 'Field replaced successfully' });
            }
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to implement a query rather than a parameter? If not then it's okay.

Comment: http://localhost/3000/api/lsbg?id="1234"

if you hit this endpoint your get the result on  this code :
app.put('/api/lsbg', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.query.id;
   res.send('ok',id)
})